# Inheriting build settings in target extension

Tags: ios, xcode

My goal is to expose a build variable from the main app target to the app target extension build process. Let's assume that the variable is `MY_BUILD_SETTING`.

1. Is inheriting a build setting variable set in the `xcconfig` file primarily in the parent main app to be used in the target app extension?
2. What kind of build settings variables are exposed for a target app extension? Is it possible to determine in the app extension build phases what is the main app target selected?

Comment: I narrowed down the scope of your question to keep it from being too broad.